# Asynchronous servlet 3.0 url mapping

Tags: servlet-3.0, url-pattern

How to set two Url patterns in Servlets 3.0 through annotation as:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/flow", asyncSupported = true)
public class FlowService extends HttpServlet
```

This example is for one url pattern but I want to set it for two urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlPatterns = {"/flow", "/low"}
```